# how can I configure emacs on Windows 7 'Meta shell'

Tags: emacs

how can I configure emacs on Windows 7 'Meta shell' command to open a cygwin shell instead of a Microsoft Windows shell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use this configuration all the time, and IMHO the best way to do it is to use a Cygwin emacs. The everything is consistent - Emacs file handling and your shell.

You can explicitly give Emacs the shell file name - that variable is cleverly named: `explicit-shell-file-name`. Set it to, say, `c:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe`, etc.

More comprehensive setup and other useful tips for this configuration: http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/setup-cygwin.el